What is this 5-pin SMD device marked "BAD"?

What is this IC that is marked "BAD". It is in a SC70-5 package and it is small

Is the pin 1 marker a dot or a small cross? If it's the latter then the manufacturer is probably Maxim (now Analog).

This could be a common design chip. I've seen about three suppliers of the same marking and the same design.

I thought it might be '8AD', not 'BAD'. Internet searches show that marking's used on ICs.

Pretty long shot, but it might be an Intersil (now Renesas) part with the marking code on the bottom.
I found this image of an Intersil ISL9003AIENZ-T using google reverse image search. The source is LCSC, but the image doesn't seem to exist on the site anymore.

While the marking code is different, the style is very similar and according to the datasheet this is likely a lot number, because the actual marking is located on the bottom. There is also another Intersil part next to it on the board (ISL97701), but this can of course just be a coincidence.


If footnote 3 says the marking is on the bottom of the chip, why is there also marking on the top?

@Colin It's probably a traceability code. I found the bottom picture, that confirms the part is marked on both sides: https://assets.lcsc.com/images/lcsc/900x900/20230130_RENESAS-ISL9003AIENZ-T_C5334511_back.jpg

Thank you for your professional answer, but there is no mark on the bottom of this chip.

@曾庆明 Well, I said it was a long shot. If you still want help to identify this chip then you need to provide more information. Take a closeup picture of the chip and try to trace where the pins connect to. Atm it's even unclear what the exact markings are. Could be 8AD or BAD.
